# meta tag in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, meta-tags

How can I put meta tag   to work only for one page. If I want to put it .aspx file, where is right place.

Thanks.

Comment: Which layout engine are you using? And are you using layouts?

Comment: I want to put this tag, to make IE 9 to behave like IE 8 just for one page <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />

Comment: i got that part, i was wonder if you are using the Razor or aspx engine, and if you are using layouts or templates respectively

Comment: I am using aspx engine, this part "and if you are using layouts or templates respectively" I do not understand. I write mu custom html if you ask that. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you haven't said yet, I'm assuming you're using the Razor engine (the "default" for new MVC3 projects). In that case, you just need to insert a new section into your layout view, and only render that section if you need to insert a meta tag.

For example, working from the stock New ASP.NET MVC 3 Project template, you would edit your `Views\Shared\_Layout.cshtml` file, and before the closing `</head>` tag, do something like this:

```
    @this.RenderSection("MetaContent", false)
</head>
```

Then, in any of your views that you needed to, add this:

```
@section MetaContent
{
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />
}
```

If you're still using the ASPX layout engine for some reason, you can accomplish the same thing using the `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder>` tags in your master page and `<asp:Content>` tags in your views.

EDIT:

Since you're using the ASP.NET Forms layout engine still, here's the same basic idea as above in aspx syntax:

In your master page, you add the tag:

```
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MetaContent" runat="server" />
</head>
```

And in your .aspx views, you add a new content section (you should already have at least two -- a title and a body):

```
<asp:Content ID="Meta" ContentPlaceHolderID="MetaContent" runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was going to suggest exactly what Michael said (+1). Another option would be to put a boolean in the ViewBag, something like:

```
ViewBag.ForceIE8Mode = true;
```

For pages that you want to force into IE8 Mode.

and then in your view, wrap the meta tag in a conditional. either

```
@if(ViewBag.ForceIE8Mode == true) {
    <meta... />
}
```

or

```
<% if(ViewBag.ForceIE8Mode == true) { %>
    <meta... />
<% } %>
```